# php_network_getaddress Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to fetch data from database and the query is working fine on sql engine. But as and when i try to trigger it from my php file where it is actually needed, I am getting php_network_getaddress error.

The form is submitting the data successfully, variables are storing the values successfullly, query is not incorrect still the error is occuring. I am unable to understand. Any help would be appreciated.

**This is my php file:**

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Error connecting to server');

mysql_select_db('db_MarkitBerry', $con); 

$cust_flow_1=0;
$cust_flow_2=0; 
$coll_flow_1=0;
$coll_flow_2=0;
    if(isset($_GET['submit']))
    {
        $date1=$_GET['datepicker'];
        $date2=$_GET['datepicker1'];

        $query=mysql_connect("SELECT DATE( date_time ) AS DATE, SUM( bill ) as amount , SUM( members ) as customers FROM  tbl_transaction WHERE DATE( date_time ) =  '2014-03-17' OR DATE( date_time ) =  '2014-03-18' GROUP BY DATE( date_time )");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
                $cust_flow_2=$row['customers'];
                $coll_flow_2=$row['amount'];
                echo $cust_flow_2;
                echo $coll_flow_2;          
        }
    }

?>
```

**This is form in html:**

```
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="get" >
            <td width="200px" style="padding:5px;" valign="top">
                <div class="style2" style="color:#FFFFFF; padding:10px; font:bold 13px Arial, Helvetica;">First Date</div>
                <div>
                    <p><input type="text" class="datepicker" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" /></p>
                </div>
                <div class="style2" style="color:#FFFFFF; padding:10px; font:bold 13px Arial, Helvetica;">Second Date</div>
                <div><p><input type="text" class="datepicker" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker1"/></p></div>
                <div>                           
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
                </div>
            </td>
            </form>
```

**This is the Error:**

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\markitberry\compare.php on line 16

Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\markitberry\compare.php on line 16

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\markitberry\compare.php on line 17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem:

`$query=mysql_connect("SELECT DATE( date_time ) AS DATE, SUM( bill ) as amount , SUM( members ) as customers FROM  tbl_transaction WHERE DATE( date_time ) =  '2014-03-17' OR DATE( date_time ) =  '2014-03-18' GROUP BY DATE( date_time )");`

You should use `mysql_query` not `mysql_connect` (your connection is already active)

PS. I know name is not important, but you should note that your `$query` variable holds results of query, not the query itself.

**NOTE: mysql_* function are deprecated! Consider using mysqli / PDO.**